# How to get PCA results in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

developing app in R shiny, and i want a PCA results of my inputted data as a part of Application. I am confused how to remove NA from data base and convert entire data in numeric and form and  PCA of data. 
i have attached my code which i have used for server.R and ui.R.

i have run this code and get error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAVDf.jpg)
what is meaning of error?
code for shniy :

```
library(factoextra)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(FactoMineR)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 20*1024^2)
```

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){

  # This reactive function will take the inputs from UI.R and use them for read.table() to read the data from the file. It returns the dataset in the form of a dataframe.
  # file$datapath -> gives the path of the file
  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    read.csv(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)

  })
```

```
# this reactive output contains the summary of the dataset and display the summary in table format
 output$filedf <- renderTable({
   if(is.null(data())){return ()}
   input$file
 })

 # this reactive output contains the summary of the dataset and display the summary in table format
 output$sub <- renderTable({
   if(is.null(data())){return ()}
   subset(data(),select=c(CNV,Clinical,Genes))

 })
 p<-sub

 # This reactive output contains the dataset and display the dataset in table format
 output$table <- renderTable({
   if(is.null(data())){return ()}
   data()
 })
 ##pca
 output$pcasub<-renderTable({
   if(is.null(data())){return ()}

 PCA(p,scale.unit = TRUE)
 })
 # the following renderUI is used to dynamically generate the tabsets when the file is loaded. Until the file is loaded, app will not show the tabset.
 output$tb <- renderUI({
   if(is.null(data()))
     h5("PRED")
   else
     tabsetPanel(tabPanel("PCA", tableOutput("pcasub")),tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("Summary", tableOutput("pcasub")))
 })
})

library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
   titlePanel("File Input"),
   sidebarLayout(
       sidebarPanel(
         #  fileInput("file","Upload clinical data file"), # fileinput() function is used to get the file upload contorl option
           fileInput("file","Upload miRNA raw read count file"), # fileinput() function is used to get the file upload contorl option

           helpText("Default max. file size is 5MB"),
           tags$hr(),
           h5(helpText("Select the read.csv parameters below")),
           checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = TRUE),
           checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "stringAsFactors", FALSE),
           br(),
           radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ',')
       ),
       mainPanel(
           uiOutput("tb")

           # use below code if you want the tabset programming in the main panel. If so, then tabset will appear when the app loads for the first time.
           #       tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("sum")),
           #                   tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("table")))
       )

   )
))
```

Comment: `sub` is a R function and you store it in the variable `p` when you do `p <- sub`.

Comment: i tried and rename sub to subs variable but got error subs object not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a few things that might help here.

First, you can have a separate `reactive` expression for your subsetted data. This can be used/shared by other tab results.

In addition, it looks like you have two identical `tableOutput` for `pcasub` in your `tabsetPanel`. Would make each unique. I changed the one for summary to `pcasummary`.

The `PCA` results won't be a data frame. One simple way to show results is using `verbatimTextOutput` and `renderPrint`. This was applied for both `pcasub` and `pcasummary`. Depending on what you need, you might want the `PCA()` in a separate reactive function, or combine with `sub_data`.

See if this is closer to what you need.

```
server <- function(input,output){

  # This reactive function will take the inputs from UI.R and use them for read.table() to read the data from the file. It returns the dataset in the form of a dataframe.
  # file$datapath -> gives the path of the file
  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    read.csv(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)
  })

  sub_data <- reactive({
    subset(data(),select=c(CNV,Clinical,Genes))
  })

  # this reactive output contains the summary of the dataset and display the summary in table format
  output$filedf <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    input$file
  })

  # this reactive output contains the summary of the dataset and display the summary in table format
  output$sub <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    sub_data()
  })

  # This reactive output contains the dataset and display the dataset in table format
  output$table <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    data()
  })

  ##pca
  output$pcasub<-renderPrint({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    PCA(sub_data(),scale.unit = TRUE)
  })

  ##pca summary
  output$pcasummary<-renderPrint({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    summary(PCA(sub_data(),scale.unit = TRUE))
  })

  # the following renderUI is used to dynamically generate the tabsets when the file is loaded. Until the file is loaded, app will not show the tabset.
  output$tb <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(data()))
      h5("PRED")
    else
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("PCA", verbatimTextOutput("pcasub")),tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("pcasummary")))
  })
}
```

Comment: thank you so  much it worked.how can i come to know that where i can use renderprint or table? can you suggest me any website or tutorial for it.it will really help me in developing application

Comment: glad to hear! i would recommend the tutorials [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson4/) in RStudio web site on shiny...lesson 4 has a list of different `output` options for the `ui`